# Go extension loading forever

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I met this problem when saving file with Go extension in VSCode

```
Header must provide a Content-Length property.
```

So it loading forever.
Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you so much.

[image: VSCode screenshot showing error]

Comment: Could you provide more context to your question? 

Suspect you are making some api call etc and there needs to be additional header

Comment: @Sebry I checked the log of my docker, there is no error when call API. I think even when i call API failed, it should have still saved the content of my code. But this notification "Saving 'controller.go': Getting code actions from ''Go''" last forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer for the extension provided a list of troubleshoot methods, please try it and if any of it fixed your problem please post it and share with the community.

[Troubleshooting Doc](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md)

UPDATE: Install/Update Tools is the solution despite being on the latest version. It make still be necessary to run this

Comment: Thank you so much @Sebry, i read Troubleshooting Doc and do step "Go: Install/Update Tools ", It really work. It is so strange when i installed newest version of Go extension, but still need update tools